# If-statements in VHDL: nested vs. multiple conditions

Tags: if-statement, vhdl, fpga, timing, synthesis

here is what my code somewhat looks like... (I know it does't compile, it's just pseudo code.)

```
signal  lowBound        :   std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal  highBound       :   std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal  result_01       :   std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal  result_02       :   std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal  result_03       :   std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

...
p_state_machine: process(RESET, CLK)
    if (RESET = '1') then
        ...
    elsif (rising_edge(CLK_I)) then
        case currentState is
            when ...
            ...
            when OUTPUT =>
                -- check if results are within interval bounds
                -- option 1
                if ((result_01 > lowBound) AND (result_02 > lowBound) AND (result_03 > lowBound) AND ...) then
                    ...
                end if;

                -- option 2
                if ((result_01 > lowBound) then
                    if ((result_02 > lowBound) then
                        if ((result_03 > lowBound) then
                            ...
                        end if;
                    end if;
                end if;
        end case;
    end if;
end process;
```

As you can see, I have a state machine and would like to output results 1-3 in the last state 'OUTPUT' but only if they are within the given interval bounds. So now I have 6 conditions that I need to check. If all are true I output results 1-3; if at least one is false, I want to set an error flag.

I am working with a Xilinx board at 25MHz but would like to have a robust design that could handle higher frequencies as well.

So now my question(s)... What's the best way to check if results 1-3 are within the given bounds?
1. I know there are multiple options but which one is the best, especially when considering timing?
2. Do options 1 and 2 from my code translate to the same hardware or is there a differnce?
3. Is it better for me to check these conditions outside the state machine in seperate (parallel) processes since I am dealing with 16-bit vectors? (I imagine having 6 nested 16-bit comparisons migth result in timing issues!?)

I am fairly new to VHDL (just graduated) and would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most designs, the challenge is writing functionally correct code, thus meeting the timing goal is trivial.  For a design at 25 MHz and to a factor of 6-10 above, and with code like that you show, the design will typically meet timing without any special effort, no matter how you write it.

Therefore, write the code so that it is easy to read and review, and let the tool handle implementation to the required frequency.  Engineering wise, that is a good approach for uncritical code, since it frees up your time for critical parts of the design.

For your question of whether to make conditions outside the process, then it does not matter timing wise.  It may reduce the size a little, if the tool does not reuse the compare result for identical results, but implements a separate compare for each.  But again, in modern FPGAs, doing 16-bit comparisons with > (which are effectively subtractions) is far from timing critical at the mentioned frequency.  Note also, that all the comparisons can be done in parallel, since the comparisons are independent.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! ...At the end you mention that all comparisons can be done in parallel. I realized that too, but can I influence that? Does the tool actually do that with option 1 from my code or does it go through the comparisons sequentially as in option 2?

Comment: The nested `if` in option 2 will (most likely) translate into the same implementation as the single `if` with `and` in option 1.  However, don't take my word for it... go ahead and try it in the tool yourself, and inspect the created design in schematic... that is a very good way to learn how the tool works, and what the implementation is based on the high level RTL :-D